# Why does Xcode complain sometimes and not always when self is used inside a block?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

Suppose the following situation:

```
  self.collectionViewController.didEndDisplayingCell = ^(CollectionViewCell *cell) {
    [self doSomething];    
  };
```

Xcode will complain that I cannot use self inside that method or I will have a retain cycle.

Then another situation. I create a class that loads an image and runs something on completion and call it like

```
[[MyImageClass sharedInstance] loadImageFromUrl:url
                             runOnCompletion:^(UIImage *image) {
                               [self doSomething];
                             }];
```

Xcode will not complain in that case and self is used inside a block!

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case:

The `self` object keep strong reference to block object.

Vice versa, block of also retain `self` object. `Since blocks capture their context, package it up, and carry it along for the ride, any reference to self (or implicit reference with an ivar) within a block also will capture a strong reference to self`. You can refer this https://blackpixel.com/writing/2014/03/capturing-myself.html

So, it will be retain cycle !

Comment: that does not explain the second case. I mean why xcode is not complaining.

Comment: Make sure you understand the 1st case. You will understand the 2nd case. About the 2nd case: the `sharedInstance` of `MyImageClass` retain the block object, block object retain `self` object, `self` object don't keep strong reference to block object. There's no retain cycle in this case !